# Warning: Use of uninitialized value substitution

Tags: perl, warnings, substitution, initialization

Why does Perl warn in this case

```
Use of uninitialized value `$new` in substitution (s///) at ./perl.pl line 8.
```

and not

```
Use of uninitialized value `$string` in substitution (s///) at ./perl.pl line 8.

#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $string;
my $new;

( $new = $string ) =~ s/^.//;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$string` is not involved in the substitution. It's on the RHS of an assignment, and having an undefined value on the RHS of an assignment shouldn't trigger a warning.

If it's ok for `$new` to be undefined, you could use

```
my $new = $string;
$new =~ s/^.// if defined($new);
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no substitution for `$string`, so it does not warn. This code copies **undef** value from `$string` into `$new` and then do substitution on `$new`.

If you want to remove this warning, you can change to this:

```
( $new = ($string // '') ) =~ s/^.//;
```

Comment: The changes undef to an empty string.